# Unable to log off remote desktop remote session profile(Remote user) and log back into admin profile

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I created a profile for a remote-user, and was able to access from my second laptop.
However, when I closed the RDC and turned the laptop off, the computer I connected via remote desktop to is showing as remote-user.

I am unable to log back into my administrator profile to make any changes.

I would like to delete this remote-user profile from my admin group.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks.